# UITableView stops scrolling after sometime

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I using standard iOS UITableView loaded with data from a local database. I have implemented the delegates and datasource and registered my UITableView cell and header and everything looks fine. However after scrolling for couple of seconds, the tableview doesn't scroll again, this happens quickly if I scroll/swing very fast, the table view would just not responding to any touch event, no scroll, no cell selection. I don't know what am doing wrong. NB: There is no new data fetch so I don't reload the tableView data once initial data is loaded. This is my datasource class: TableCell is custom UITableViewCell while HeaderCell is custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView

```
func registerCells(tableView: UITableView) {
    tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: tableCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: tableCell)
    
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: headerCell, bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: headerCell)
    
    print("\(sourceTag) register cells")
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return viewModel.getNumberSections()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.viewModel.getNumberRowsInSection(section)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = viewModel.dataValues[indexPath.section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCell, for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let quote = data.quotes[indexPath.row]
    cell.setupWithQuote(quote, withSelectionDelegate: quoteSelectionDelegate)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let data = viewModel.dataValues[section]
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: enquiryCell) as! HeaderCell
    headerCell.setupData(data)
    return headerCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 161.0
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //print("I'm scrolling!")
    NSLog("I'm scrolling!")
}
```

Comment: Are you running the app from Xcode? Are you sure it hasn't crashed? Are you sure it's not stopped at a breakpoint? If neither of those, common problems are updating the UI from a background thread or getting into an infinite loop. I think you'll need to post more code (TableCell and HeaderCell classes) so we can see what's going on in `setupWithQuote()` and `setupData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DonMag comment pointed me to the right direction. There was a delegate method which was vetted assigned multiple times which led to a cyclic issue and hence table views cell rendering issue